# Boolean Modifier doesn't work, it just smooth shades my mesh

Tags: modifiers

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make an interior for this low poly build. I want to clean the inside by removing unwanted parts of different objects through Boolean Modifier. However, when I use it it doesn't work. Anyone know how to fix this?

[Download Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Udw1VN7tu-sLI6xg9IK9BcTOUFvKtPug/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your face orientation is wrong.

Tap on viewport overlays and check "face orientation".

[image]

you will get:

[image]

red means outside (which is wrong, you shouldn't see this "normally" - with some exceptions, e.g. you go with camera inside a box), blue means outside.

So select the house:

Press Tab for edit mode and A to select all -> Mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside

[image]

then you get:

[image]

Hide your house again and you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please check the checkmark left to my answer? Thank you!