# Shading issues on a mesh

Tags: modeling, topology

I have shading issues which I highlighted in the pictures below and I don't know how to fix them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check face orientation?

Comment: @Chris how you can do that?

Comment: Read my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/226782/86978

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your normals are inverted on the selected meshes:

[image]

Select them both, go into edit mode, and press Shift+N on your keyboard (Remember to select the meshes with A first and don't forget to select them both). This will fix the issue.

[image]